# Laravel 11 Staudenmeir BelongsToThrough Undefined Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, load, relationship

I have a problem using Staudenmeir's BelongsToThrough package. This is what I have in my Laravel 11 project:

Database:

```
* ----------------------- *
|          users          |
* ----------------------- *
|   + id                  |
|   + address_id          |
* ----------------------- *

* ----------------------- *
|        addresses        |
* ----------------------- *
|   + id                  |
|   + country_code_id     |
* ----------------------- *

* ----------------------- *
|      country_codes      |
* ----------------------- *
|   + id                  |
* ----------------------- *
```

User.php

```
class User extends Model
{
   public function address(): BelongsTo
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(Address::class);
   }

   public function country_code(): BelongsToThrough
   {
      return $this->belongsToThrough(CountryCode::class, Address::class);
   }
}
```

Address.php

```
class Address extends Model
{
   public function user(): HasOne
   {
      return $this->hasOne(User::class);
   }

   public function country_code(): BelongsTo
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(CountryCode::class);
   }
}
```

CountryCode.php

```
class CountryCode extends Model
{
   public function address(): HasMany
   {
      return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
   }

   public function users(): HasManyThrough
   {
      return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, Address::class);
   }
}
```

UserController.php

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function show(Request $request, User $user)
   {
      # access countryCode through address from user
      # not working:
      return (new UserResource($user))->load('country_code');
   }
}
```

CountryCodeController.php

```
class CountryCodeController extends Controller
{
   public function show(Request $request, CountryCode $countryCode)
   {
      # access user through address from countryCode
      # working:
      return (new CountryCodeResource($countryCode))->load('user');
   }
}
```

I can query without problems:

- `UserResource->load('address')`
- `AddressResource->load('country_code')`
- `CountryCodeResource->load('address')`
- `AddressResource->load('user')`
- `AddressResource->load('users')` with hasManyThrough()

**Now the problem:**

If i try the inverse of the hasManyThrough, **belongsToThrough** provided by [Staudenmeir](https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through) (using `UserResource->load('country_code')`), I always get the the following error message:

```
"message": "Call to undefined relationship [country_code] on model [App\\Models\\User]."
```

Is there any problem in my code or have i misunderstood something? In my opinion all necessary relations should be defined and even the hasManyThrough works like a charm.

If you need any further information, just ask.

Thanks for your help in advance!

**Edit**

I also tried it with **camelCase** naming, but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: I doubt this would fix it, but naming convention for methods is `camelCase`, so it should be `countryCode()` instead of `country_code()`

Answer (score 0):

why not use `hasOneThrough` like this: [document](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through)

```php
   public function carOwner(): HasOneThrough
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(Owner::class, Car::class);
    }
```

Comment: This is the other way round. This works, but for my database it would mean showing the **user** that has a specific **country_code**. But i need the **country_code** used by a specific **user**.

For my database I need the ```user belongsTo address belongsTo country_codes``` relation and not the ```country_code hasMany address hasOne user``` relation. If that makes sense